# How is the ciphertext labeled with a set of attributes in Key-Policy Attribute-based Encryption (KP-ABE)

Tags: encryption, abe

My question is about Key-Policy ABE (KP-ABE). What does it mean when a "Ciphertext is Labeled with set of attribute"? How is it labeled?

Comment: Maybe you could mention where you are reading this?

Answer (score 3):

The first Attribute-based Encryption scheme was introduced by Sahai and Waters in 2005: [*Fuzzy Identity-Based Encryption*](http://eprint.iacr.org/2004/086). It worked by associating a set of attributes with both the ciphertext and the private key of the user.

Take for example the ciphertext which is encrypted with the attribute set $\{A, B, C\}$ and the private key of some user with the attribute set $\{B, C, D\}$. If the system threshold $d$ is chosen as 2 then the user would be able to decrypt the ciphertext with because the cut set of the ciphertext attribute set and the private key attribute set is of size 2 which is greater or equal to the global threshold $d$.

This is of course not very useful, because this only achieves cryptographic access control based on set overlap. One generally wants to use more complicated *policies* which are more expressive than simple sets. Such expressive policies where later achieved by Goyal et al. in 2006: [*Attribute-Based Encryption for Fine-Grained Access Control of Encrypted Data*](http://eprint.iacr.org/2006/309) (KP-ABE).

Instead of using two sets, the private key of the user is generated (associated) from a boolean formula (*policy*) of attributes and the ciphertext is encrypted with an attribute set. For example, the ciphertext may have been encrypted with the set $\{A, B\}$. Now we have two users with private keys from two different policies. $$SK_1=\text{Keygen}(MSK, ``A\ \text{and}\ (B\ \text{or}\ C)")$$ and $$SK_2=\text{Keygen}(MSK, ``A\ \text{and}\ (C\ \text{or}\ D)").$$

You should see that the user who possesses $SK_1$ can easily decrypt the ciphertext, because ciphertext was encrypted with $B$, the clauses $B\ \text{or}\ C$ is fulfilled as well as the $A$. Since both clauses are fulfilled, the $\texttt{and}$-gate is also fulfilled. This means that the attribute set *satisfies* the policy in the private key and $SK_1$ can decrypt the ciphertext.

The user who possesses $SK_2$ cannot decrypt the same ciphertext, because the necessary clause $C\ \text{or}\ D$ is not fulfilled by the attributes present in the ciphertext. Therefore the $\texttt{and}$-gate cannot be fulfilled and $SK_2$ cannot decrypt the ciphertext.

There is also [CP-ABE](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~bwaters/publications/papers/cp-abe.pdf) by Bethencourt where the roles are reversed, because a policy is used to encrypt the ciphertext and private keys are generated from attribute sets.

Comment: I understand how with the threshold policy a Secret Sharing Scheme can be used to generate a secret key to decrypt the ciphertext, but how does this work in the KP-ABE example? If you use `{A,B}` to create the ciphertext, how can a `SK1 "A and (B or C)"` and `SK3 "A and (B or E)"` both decrypt the cipher text, since the secret key must be different right?

Comment: @user1226868 Sorry, I've never looked at KP-ABE schemes in detail (because I still don't understand the use case perfectly), but they use a tree in the same way: inputting the attributes at the leaves and working their way up the tree to get the secret.